# Was the play in the Star Trek TNG episode “Frame of Mind” a real play?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I just rewatched the TNG episode "Frame of Mind" and I was wondering if the play that Crusher was directing (and Riker and Data were starring in) was a real play or maybe based on a real play?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was wholly invented by the writers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Very likely, no.

According to Memory Alpha, *[Frame of Mind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Frame_of_Mind)* was a play **written** and **directed** by Dr. Beverly Crusher.

According to this, we can exclude that it is a real play, given that a fictional character is credited  to be the author.

[Background information](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Frame_of_Mind_(episode)#Background_information) for this episode reports that it was written as an answer to *"What if Riker woke up in an alien insane asylum and had no idea how he got there and was told he was crazy?"*.

Given this information, we can also rule out it being *based* on a real play, because it seems that the actual play is nothing more than a plot device to put Riker in the intended situation.

Anyway, Brannon Braga, the episode writer, said that some influence can be traced to Roman Polanksi's *[Repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repulsion_(film))*, one of his favorite movies.